# How-to show last 5 posts

Tags: posts

How-to show last 5 posts that are published after current post?

Explained on image below:

[IMAGE FOR EXPLAINE](http://s017.radikal.ru/i401/1111/99/6bd645f47f86.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $wpdb, $post; // Uses current POST here
$IDs = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `ID` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE `post_type`='{$post->post_type}' AND `post_status`='publish' AND `ID`<{$post->ID}
    ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 5;");
```

This function lists the 5 posts with IDs lower then `ID 176` that are of `post_type='post'` and `post_status='publish'`. Change post_type if you use a custom post type to whatever you need. You can also order by `post_date_gmt` if you want.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function custom_prev_posts($limit = 5){
  global $wpdb, $post;
  $html = '';
  $prev_posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_date < '%s' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT $limit", $post->post_date ) ); 

  if($prev_posts){
    $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach ( $prev_posts as $prev_post  ) {
    $html .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) . '">' .$prev_post->post_title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $html;
}
 echo custom_prev_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the offset arg will achieve what you are after:

```
 $posts_arr = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=1');
```